# Is it possible to close the instance of a long-running process on Deploy on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I'm executing a long-running process on the node `node-red-node-daemon` on `Node-RED`. However, all the times that I redeploy the project it creates a new instance of the script that was running (it doesn't kill the instance that was already running and it creates a new one on deploy, so if I deploy my project 10 times, the OS will run 10 instances of my script).

[image]

As far as I understood from this node, it was supposed to kill the script when `Node-RED` closes (I'm assuming that closing `Node-RED` is something that is done on deploy). But it doesn't work as I expected. Am I missing something? Is it possible to kill a long-running process on `Node-RED` while redeploying? So we don't create new instances of it?

---

**EDIT**

The long-running process that I said in my question is a bash script running the `inotifywait` command on a Linux machine (you can't use it on Windows). Here is a simplified version of it:

```
#!/bin/bash

WATCHEDFOLDER='/home/user/watchedfolder'
id=''
event=''
file=''

main () {
   if [ "$event" == "MOVED_TO" ]; then
      echo -n "$id""$file"
   fi
}

inotifyInterruption () {
   inotifywait --format="%w^%e^%f" -q -m -e move "$WATCHEDFOLDER" |
      while IFS='^' read idLocal eventLocal fileLocal; do
         id="$idLocal"
         event="$eventLocal"
         file="$fileLocal"
         main
      done
}   

inotifyInterruption
```

The idea here is that all the times that a new file is moved to a specific folder, the script will print the full path of the file (and consequently send it to the next node as msg.payload on Node-RED). To sum up, the problem with creating new instances in this script is that it will work as if there were 10 files with the same name arriving in the watched folder after deploying it 10 times...

Comment: Change the deploy mode (click the arrow on the end of the deploy button) to only deploy modified nodes, then as long as you are not changing that node then it won't start a new instance.

Comment: Also the kill will very much depend on how your script is written, Please edit the question to include the script.

Comment: @hardillb That actually solves my problem temporarily, thanks! I've edited the question explaining a little more about the kind of script that I'm running. It'd be great if there was a way of killing the running instance of my script while redeploying it (without creating a new script for that).